# Webpack Externals , load a local file on runtime

Tags: javascript, webpack, runtime, external, webpack-4

I have a file `uiConfig.json`, it has some `server URL`, and the DevOps team changes the files based on the environment.
`
I am trying to load this file on runtime using webpack.

So far I have tried the following.

1. Using Webpack Externals

```
//webpack.config.js
  
externals: {
   'uiConfig': JSON.stringify(require('./uiConfig.json'))
},
```

copied uiConfig at root path of build directory

```
//app.js

import uiConfig from 'uiConfig'
```

2. Fetching the uiConfig from the script tag and exposing the url to global window object.
   This method seems to be working sometimes, but its not consistent

```
<script type="application/javascript"> 
        window.uiConfig = {}
          fetch('./uiConfig.json').then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          }).then((data) => {
            window.uiConfig = data
        })
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong, how could I tackle this problem?

Appreciate your help.